# How to use axios to get api items in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, react-hooks

I am learning Redux so this may be a basic question and answer but here we go.

I am trying to fetch a list of items from my backend api `(/api/items)` and pass them into my `ShoppingList.js` component so that when the component loads the list of items will be displayed. I think that I have to fetch the data in the action, and then call that action in the useEffect hook in the react component, but I am not too sure as I can't seem to get it to work.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Redux.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import axios from 'axios';

const initialState = {
    items: [],
    loading: false,
};

export const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_ITEMS':
            return {
                ...state,
                items: action.payload,
                loading: false,
            };
        case 'ADD_ITEM':
            return {
                ...state,
                items: [...state.items, action.payload],
            };
        case 'DELETE_ITEM':
            return {
                ...state,
                items: state.items.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload),
            };
        case 'ITEMS_LOADING':
            return {
                ...this.state,
                loading: true,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const getItemsAction = () => ({
    return(dispatch) {
    console.log('here');
    axios.get('api/items').then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        dispatch({ type: 'GET_ITEMS', payload: response.data });
    });
},
});

export const addItemAction = item => ({
    type: 'ADD_ITEM',
    payload: item,
});

export const deleteItemAction = item => ({
    type: 'DELETE_ITEM',
    payload: item,
});

export const setItemsLoading = () => ({
    type: 'ITEMS_LOADING',
});
```

ShoppingList.js

```
export default function ShoppingList() {
    const items = useSelector(state => state.items);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const addItem = name => dispatch(addItemAction(name));
    const deleteItem = id => dispatch(deleteItemAction(id));

    useEffect(() => {
        //call get items dispatch?
        getItemsAction();
    });

    return (
        <div className="container mx-auto">
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    const name = prompt('Enter Item');
                    if (name) {
                        // setItems([...items, { id: uuid(), name: name }]);
                        addItem({
                            id: uuid(),
                            name: name,
                        });
                    }
                }}
                className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded mt-4"
            >
                Add Item
            </button>

            <ul className="mt-4">
                <TransitionGroup className="shopping-list">
                    {items.map(({ id, name }) => (
                        <CSSTransition
                            key={id}
                            timeout={500}
                            classNames="fade"
                            style={{ marginBottom: '0.5rem' }}
                        >
                            <li>
                                {' '}
                                <button
                                    className="bg-red-500 rounded px-2 mr-2 text-white"
                                    onClick={deleteItem.bind(this, id)}
                                >
                                    &times;
                                </button>
                                {name}
                            </li>
                        </CSSTransition>
                    ))}
                </TransitionGroup>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are close to where you need to be, the missing piece is that redux is synchronous, so you need to use something like `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga` to handle async actions such as network requests.

Once you have setup whatever library you want, you would call it similarly to calling a redux action, from a `useEffect` like you suggest.

So for example, if you use a `thunk`:

```
export const getItemsAction = () => ({
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.get('api/items').then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            dispatch({ type: 'GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS', payload: response.data })
        }).catch(err => dispatch({ type: 'GET_ITEMS_ERROR', error: err })
    },
})
```

Then you could call it from your `effect`:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getItemsAction())
    }, []);
```

Make sure you add an empty dependency array if you only want to call it once, otherwise it will get called every time your component refreshes.

Note that the `thunk` is able to dispatch other redux actions, and I changed a few of your actions types to make it more clear what is going on;
`GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS` is setting your successful response & `GET_ITEMS_ERROR` sets any error if there is one.

Comment: so would that look something like this? 

`export const getItemsAction = () => ({
 return(dispatch) {
  axios.get('api/items').then(response => {
   console.log(response);
   dispatch({ type: 'GET_ITEMS', payload: response.data });
  });
 },
});`

Comment: Yeah, I edited my answer to help explain how I would do it with thunks

Comment: Okay thank you, I have made the changes you suggested but now i get an `Actions may not have an undefined "type" property.` error in the useEffect hook. Any idea why that is happening? The type is set as 'GET_ITEMS' with the case for 'GET_ITEMS' in my reducer.

Comment: You need to make sure any actions types dispatched by the thunk are in your reducer, so make sure GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS and GET_ITEMS_ERROR are in your reducer.  GET_ITEMS itself is not needed

Comment: Right, the GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS and GET_ITEMS_ERROR are in my reducer but I still get the same error message at `dispatch(getItemsAction());`